# Using an if statement within a transaction to delete multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, transactions, conditional-statements

I'm a junior dev trying to write code that separates out beeps that are owned by a user and beeps that another user is authorized for.

The beeps come from a device that a user owns. An owner can authorize other users to use that device and receive their own beep alerts. This gives us two different types of beeps: owned beeps and authorized beeps. I want the authorized user to be able to delete multiple beep events at the same time and only their own, while I want the owner to be able to delete multiple beeps and those beep's corresponding events.

The application I'm working on is very large and architecturally has been set up with this functionality for the owner to delete only single beeps.

The beep events go through a method that talks to a separate application that handles the deletion of events through the device_broker method.

What I ended up doing was a transaction with an if statement and then looping through an each iterator, checking each beep that's passing through if it was owned or authorized by the user.

My problem is that my broker_mock test isn't receiving any arguments. When I use a debugger on the code, the methods all seem to be working, so I'm very puzzled. Is using an if statement with an each loop a good idea? Also wrapping it all in a transaction means that if one tiny thing breaks, it doesn't work. Is there a better alternative?

Thanks for any wisdom or light you can shed.

```
  beeps_controller.rb

  def bulk_deletion
      BulkBeepRemover.run!(params[:beep_ids], current_user)
  end

  bulk_beep_remover.rb

  class BulkBeepRemover
    class Unauthorized < StandardError; end;
    attr_reader :beep_ids, :user, :beeps

    attr_accessor :owned_beeps, :unowned_beeps

    def self.run!(beep_ids, user)
      new(beep_ids, user).run!
    end

    def initialize(beep_ids, user)
      @beep_ids = beep_ids
      raise Unauthorized if user.nil?
      @user = user
    end

    def beeps
      @beeps ||= Beep.finished.find(beep_ids)
    end

    def device_broker
      @device_broker ||= $device_broker
    end

    attr_writer :device_broker

    def run!
      #handles deletion of the owned beeps
      Beep.transaction do
        beeps.each do |beep|
          if beep.device.is_owner?(user)
             beep.destroy
             remove_beep_event(beep.id)
          end
         # elsif beep.device.is_authorized?(user) logic goes here
        end
      end
    end

 private

  def remove_beep_event(beep_id)
    device_broker.publish('beep_deleted', { beep_id: beep_id })
  end

dings_spec.rb

  describe "POST /clients_api/beeps/bulk_deletion" do
    let(:user_id)        { user.id }

    let!(:shared_beep_1) { create(:beep, id: 33, device:       authorized_device, state: :completed) }
    let!(:shared_beep_2) { create(:beep, id: 34, device: authorized_device, state: :completed) }
    let!(:owned_beep_1)  { create(:beep, id: 35, device: owned_device, state: :completed) }
    let!(:owned_beep_2)  { create(:beep, id: 36, device: owned_device, state: :completed) }

    before do
      post "/clients_api/beeps/:beep_id/bulk_deletion",        default_params.merge(beep_ids: [shared_beep_1.id, shared_beep_2.id,     owned_beep_1.id, owned_beep_2.id], user_id: user.id)
      allow_any_instance_of(BulkBeepRemover).to receive(:device_broker).and_return(broker_mock)
    end

    context "the owner's array of beep ids" do
      let(:beep_id) { owned_beep_2.id }


      it "deletes the beeps" do
        expect { Beep.find(beep_id) }.to     raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
      end

      it "publishes the owner beep_deleted event" do
        expect(broker_mock).to     have_received(:publish).with("beep_deleted", { beep_id: beep_id })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `/clients_api/beeps/:beep_id/bulk_deletion` route doesn't take a `:user_id` argument.  As such, there's no parameter for the `user_id` arguments to be passed.

Also, the parameter name `:beep_id` is mismatched from the usage in the test, which calls it `:beep_ids`; this may or may not play an issue, but it's worth making sure that the names are aligned to avoid conflicts.

You asked about the `if` statement inside an `each` block, and there's no problem with that at all; this is very common in Ruby code.  You've done just find with the `if` statement.

Regarding the transaction, you **can** protect the transaction block with a `rescue`, but whether you **should** depends entirely on a few consideration.

1) The purpose of the transaction block is important, and not at all obvious from the code.  You'll have to determine if the transaction is strictly for efficiency in updating the database (to reduce the number of SQL calls), or if it's to maintain transactional integrity.

2) You have to find out whether using `rescue` in this way is considered acceptable practice in your organization; it's very much verboten in some organizations.  When it's not allowed, you must take steps to ensure that the exception that occurs will be avoided before it can happen.  One such way is to query whether it's safe to perform an operation prior to performing it, and avoid doing so if it's not safe.

3) You have to know whether it's acceptable to disregard deleting beeps within the transaction, for any reason, without giving proper feedback; or, on the flip side, determine what the proper feedback mechanism is.  Processes that silently fail are not well-prized.  For instance, if someone asks for a beep to be deleted, and the deletion returns successfully, it can be assumed that the beep has been deleted; if not, the user of the process should be informed in some way that it was not, so that they may take appropriate action, even if that action is simply relaying the message upstream.

Realistically, with questions about the use of the transaction and whether the `if` can (or *should*) be used, you may be treading into software design territory, and you may need clarification on the goals and restrictions that you have to work with.  This is life of a software developer; every simple question has a number of complex considerations.  Learn to recognize and deal with them appropriately, and you'll be well ahead of the pack!

Comment: Thank you Michael for the great response! I appreciate your time and advice. As for the problem I was having, it was indeed inside my rspec test. I was calling the api before my stubbed parameters. Which was a very noob thing to not notice.

Thank you again for enlightening me a bit more on transactions and thinking through their implementation.

This was my fix:

`before do
        allow_any_instance_of(BulkBeepRemover).to receive(:device_broker).and_return(broker_mock)
        post "/clients_api/beeps/:beep_id/bulk_deletion", default_params.merge(params)
      end`